# How I can delete some object's keys and return sorted array from object's values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array like this:

```
0: {__typename: "SegmentType", start: "0", end: "316", id: "f4d3487f-937d-4db1-8b24-597010d1258d"}
1: {__typename: "SegmentType", start: "218", end: "534", id: "9b8780db-4101-4ef8-975b-9b309c5ca6b6"}
2: {__typename: "SegmentType", start: "137", end: "202", id: "c702ef6a-b7a4-4383-b317-e71705340326"}
3: {__typename: "SegmentType", start: "602", end: "738", id: "0a353a44-b5f4-4b04-ba82-104dd6d60a3b"}
```

I need to delete 2 keys - `__typename:` and `id`. After this object should cointains `start` and `end`. And then I need to create and array from all of these object and it should be like this:

```
[0, 316, 218, 534, 137, 202, 602, 738]
```

It means that the order should be like this:

```
[start, end, start, end, start, end]
```

So could you help me to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Use `flatMap` to get the expected output.

Comment: Have you tried a for loop? `for(const o of array) output.push(o.start, o.end)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want `flatMap((el) => [el.start, el.end])`

```js
console.log([{__typename: "SegmentType", start: "0", end: "316", id: "f4d3487f-937d-4db1-8b24-597010d1258d"},
{__typename: "SegmentType", start: "218", end: "534", id: "9b8780db-4101-4ef8-975b-9b309c5ca6b6"},
{__typename: "SegmentType", start: "137", end: "202", id: "c702ef6a-b7a4-4383-b317-e71705340326"},
{__typename: "SegmentType", start: "602", end: "738", id: "0a353a44-b5f4-4b04-ba82-104dd6d60a3b"}]
.flatMap((el) => [el.start, el.end]))
```

Comment: If we're already using the modern stuff: `.flatMap(({start, end}) => [start, end])`